# tkinter/python menu display problems on MacBook Pro (late 2011) running OSX 10.11.5

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, osx-elcapitan

I had been running Python 2.7.11 with Tkinter just fine until I recently tried tkinter Menu stuff.  per following:

https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk

I updated to Python 3.5.1, installed ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0, even installed XCode 7.3.1 from Apple Apps.  I have been using PyCharm Community Edition (updated to latest) and most recently been trying idle3 from the terminal.  I have verified my python version and tcl version and still all I get is window.  I can not get a menubar or populate any menu stuff in the window.  I am desperate for some help, Please!  This is the latest code I have run:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('GUI')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        menu_ = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu_)

        file = Menu(menu_)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)
        menu_.add_cascade(label='File', menu_=file)

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

root = Tk()  
root.geometry("400x300")  
app = Window(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

------> more info:  per:  Tadhg McDonald-Jensen suggestion this is what
I typed in idle3 to get the information Tadhg suggested:

```
from tkinter import *
import idlelib.macosxSupport as macSupport

root = Tk()
macSupport._initializeTkVariantTests(root)
print(macSupport._tk_type)
```

The console returned:
cocoa

Where do I go from here?   Could anyone using a MacBook Pro with the set-up I am running offer a minimal Python Menu() menubar program that runs?

Bryan Oakley, Thanks so Much for graciously formatting my code properly for this forum!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you aware that on a mac the menubar doesn't appear on the window? It appears across the top of the display like any other mac app.

Comment: would you be able to do `import idlelib.macosxSupport as macSupport ; macSupport._initializeTkVariantTests(root) ; print(macSupport._tk_type)` ? That would indicate what kind of setup you have on your mac, I believe the menu maybe handled differently if you are using Aqua or Carbon.

Comment: Thanks so much for the code formatting - it was my first post and I was frustrated.  I have heard that about Mac, but I was simply getting Python next to the apple.  The YouTube guy I was following sentdex does do his stuff on windows mostly.

Comment: Tadhg  thanks so much, I will give that a try.   Richard

Comment: Tadhg:  I got 'cocoa' as a response.  Where do I go from there?  Richard